Recommendations for performing intersectional analysis of medical vulnerability using composite household service indicators
I am working on a dataset to analyze the intersectional vulnerability in medical access due to socioeconomic factors. Specifically, I have created a composite household service indicator that sums up the availability of various basic services. I want to examine how this indicator, along with other factors like gender and education, influences medical vulnerability.
Dataset Details:
Home_Status_Indicator: This is a composite numeric indicator representing the availability of basic household services. It is calculated by summing up the presence (coded as 'Yes') of the following services:
Water: Availability of an aqueduct.
Electricity: Availability of an energy connection.
Gas: Availability of a gas connection.
Sewerage: Availability of sewerage.
Garbage Collection: Availability of garbage collection services.
Internet: Availability of an internet connection.
For example, if a household has water, electricity, gas, and internet, the Home_Status_Indicator would be 4.
High_Vulnerability_Medical: A binary indicator (1 for high vulnerability, 0 for low) that represents whether individuals did not seek needed medical attention due to financial constraints.
Gender: A categorical variable indicating the gender of the individual (Male or Female).
Education: A categorical variable representing the highest level of education attained by the individual (e.g., Primary, Secondary, Tertiary).
Objectives:
Assess the impact of the Home_Status_Indicator on medical vulnerability.
Analyze the interaction between the Home_Status_Indicator, gender, and education on medical vulnerability.
Questions:
What are the best statistical methods or practices for performing an intersectional analysis with these variables?
How can I effectively assess the combined impact of socioeconomic factors and demographic variables on medical vulnerability?
Are there specific techniques or models that can handle the interaction effects between these variables in a robust way?
